# Up to how many elements a Dictionary can store in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a program in C#. I keep on adding elements to a dictionary. At a points when dictionary has 5999471 elements and when I add one more element it give out of memory exemption in mscorlib.dll.

Comment: Seems like you already figured it out...

Comment: A question that rises is: Why do you need such a large collection in memory? I'm not being sceptical (yet), just curious (for now).

Comment: It looks like I need to store these elements in a database because it is not accepting more than 5999471 elements.

Comment: @Silvermind I am working on a permutation of a sequence of the numbers. For E.g. for 20 numbers I'll be producing 20!(Factorial) sets. So the result is so huge it is unable to fit in dictionary.

Comment: Then you have valid point regarding 'why so many' and Eric Lippert's intro in his answer for the duplicate makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The capacity of a Dictionary is the number of elements
>   the Dictionary can hold. As elements are added to a
>   Dictionary, the capacity is automatically increased as
>   required by reallocating the internal array.
>
> **For very large Dictionary objects, you can increase the
>   maximum capacity to 2 billion elements** on a 64-bit system by setting
>   the enabled attribute of the [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) configuration
>   element to true in the run-time environment.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enables arrays that are greater than 2 gigabytes (GB) in total size but only in 64bit machines.

Also keep in mind that that is the maximum amount of *objects* the Dictionary may hold, but your system memory may not allow you to go that far.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but why they have kept limit to dictinary

Comment: Performance? System stability? Ease of usage?
Only they know for sure, but to me, even 2B items in memory is out of the question, you should be using a database and paging the results.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to use database or pagination here in this case.

Comment: Too big of a topic to discuss here, but look for a tutorial on EntityFramework, that will get you started and solve your doubts.